# Secondary y-axis using seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot a bar chart and a line chart as a single plot and inclined to use `seaborn` due to its nice formatting features. However, when I do `df1.plot(kind='bar',...)` followed by `df1.plot(kind='line',..., secondary_y=True)`, I get similar outcome as below, i.e., no line chart but no error.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Sample dataframe.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(datetime(2020,1,1), periods=699).tolist(), 'amount':range(1,700), 'balance':np.cumsum(range(1,700))})
df1.loc[:, 'month'] = df1['date'].dt.to_period("M")
df1.loc[:, 'month_str'] = df1['date'].dt.year.astype(str) + '-' + df1['date'].dt.month.astype(str)
df1.loc[:, 'month_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.month.dt.year*10000+df1.month.dt.month*100+1,format='%Y%m%d')

# Case-1: This doesn't work.
df2 = df1.groupby(['month']).agg({'amount':'sum','balance':'sum'})
sns.barplot(x='month', y='amount', data=df2.reset_index(), palette="Blues_d")
ax2 = plt.twinx()
sns.lineplot(x='month', y='balance', data=df2.reset_index(), color='red', markers=True, ax=ax2)

# Case-2: This doesn't work (as intended, if months grow they will not auto-adjust max numbers to show and not sorted).    
df2 = df1.groupby(['month_str']).agg({'amount':'sum','balance':'sum'})
sns.barplot(x='month_str', y='amount', data=df2.reset_index(), palette="Blues_d")
ax2 = plt.twinx()
sns.lineplot(x='month_str', y='balance', data=df2.reset_index(), color='red', markers=True, ax=ax2)

# Case-3: This doesn't work either.
df2 = df1.groupby(['month_dt']).agg({'amount':'sum','balance':'sum'})
sns.barplot(x='month_dt', y='amount', data=df2.reset_index(), palette="Blues_d")
ax2 = plt.twinx()
sns.lineplot(x='month_dt', y='balance', data=df2.reset_index(), color='red', markers=True, ax=ax2)
```

**Case-1**:
[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py", line 46, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\seaborn\relational.py", line 703, in lineplot
    p.plot(ax, kwargs)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\seaborn\relational.py", line 529, in plot
    line, = ax.plot(x, y, **kws)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1745, in plot
    self.add_line(line)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 1964, in add_line
    self._update_line_limits(line)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 1986, in _update_line_limits
    path = line.get_path()
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 1011, in get_path
    self.recache()
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 653, in recache
    x = _to_unmasked_float_array(xconv).ravel()
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 1289, in _to_unmasked_float_array
    return np.asarray(x, float)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 83, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Period'
```

**Case-2**:
[image]

**Case-3**:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build a dummy x axis and replace the values with the month data after constructing the plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df2 = df1.groupby(['month']).agg({'amount':'sum','balance':'sum'})

# helper axis
data = df2.reset_index()
data['xaxis'] = range(len(data))

sns.barplot(x='xaxis', y='amount', data=data, palette="Blues_d", ax=ax)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
sns.lineplot(x='xaxis', y='balance', data=data, color='red', markers=True, ax=ax2)

# replace helper axis with actual data
ax.set_xticklabels(data['month'].values, rotation = 45, ha="right")
```

[image]

Comment: good idea +1, could also do `data = df2.reset_index().reset_index()` and use `x='index'` without manually creating `xaxis`

Comment: @tdy I think yours is more elegant

Comment: @warped this is very helpful. Is there a way to show **single** legend for both primary and secondary y-axis?

Comment: I do something like take `lin1, lbl1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()` for both axes, `ax1` and `ax2`. Then remove legend from both using `ax1.legend_.remove()` and `ax2.legend_.remove()`. Finally, do `ax1.legend(lin1 + lin2, lbl1 + lbl2, loc='best', fancybox=True, framealpha=0.5)`. This seem to give funny output of not showing line color in legend. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Gerry what do you want the legend to read? As it is, the get_handles_labels just returns empty lists.

Comment: @warped Lets say I want to provide custom labels; say in this case 'Amt' for Amount and 'Bal' for balance and show the color code in legend.

Comment: @Gerry there is always the trick with plotting an empty list: plt.plot([],[], color='red', label='balance'); plt.legend(). For the barplot you need to decide which of the colors you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a dummy x axis. Try the following code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample dataframe.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(pd.datetime(2020,1,1), periods=699).tolist(), 'amount':range(1,700), 'balance':np.cumsum(range(1,700))})
df1.loc[:, 'month'] = df1['date'].dt.to_period("M")
df2 = df1.groupby(['month']).agg({'amount':'sum','balance':'sum'})
g = sns.barplot(x='month', y='amount', data=df2.reset_index(), palette="Blues_d")
g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
sns.lineplot(x=range(len(df2.reset_index())), y='balance', data=df2.reset_index(), color='red', markers=True, ax=g.twinx())
```

[image]